# steps_per_epoch in fit_generator keras

Tags: keras

Online I have found lots of explanations for steps_per_epoch.

Summary: steps_per_epoch = len(train_data)/batch_size

But I figure I can set the steps_per_epoch as 1 when I test my code.
But after the 1 was given to steps_per_epoch, the generator has rolled over 1 time.

That confused me.

I think keras don't know how many datasets I have for training. So the parameter steps_per_epoch can tell keras the numbers of dataset for one epoch.

Can I set the steps_per_epoch as 1 when i test my code?

Comment: There seems to be no question here?

Comment: `steps_per_epoch` is to set manually the number of batches to go through before counting an epoch.